# How could I add arrows to the axis of a figure?

Tags: plotting

It is easy for me to add arrows to the axes of the a figure by taking advantage of `AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[]` when the differences between the horizontal and vertical coordinates is small. For instance, by using

```
Plot[1/x, {x, -20, 20}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.03}]]
```

the arrows appear at both the horizontal and vertical axis.
However, I don't know how to add arrows to the ones whose differences are big. For example, when the following program is run

```
Plot[1/x^5, {x, -20, 20}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.00003}]]
```

the arrows cannot be seen obviously? I want to know how I can make the arrows to be found evidently just as the previous one?

Comment: @rm: [tag:graphics] might be a better fit; OP's question deals with primitives, as opposed to the plot itself.

Comment: @J.M. The choice of primitives is not the issue here... it's just one of padding. Feel free to revert if you think graphics is better.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
Plot[1/x^5, {x, -20, 20}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}], 
     ImagePadding -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Do you need the first 0.0?

Comment: @cormullion only as a placeholder for specifying for example `Arrowheads[{-0.05, 0.05}]` later

Comment: I know that ImagePadding was needed but I don't see why, nor why the default ImagePadding depends on the parameters of Arrowhead.

Comment: @DavidCarraher I've to think about that. Probably it's due to the time in which the image size is determined (something in the plot scaling may be still unknown). You may post a question :)

Answer (score 4):

A way to overcome this problem is drawing arrows separately and combining them with the main plot through the Show function:

```
PR = {{-20, 20}, {-2.1*10^-4, 2.1*10^-4}};(*PlotRange*)
AO = {0, 0};(*AxesOrigin*)
extX = 3;
extY = 3*10^-5;
lw = 0.003;(*width of arrows*)

PR1 = {{PR[[1, 1]], PR[[1, 2]] + extX}, {PR[[2, 1]], PR[[2, 2]] + extY}};
Show[
   Plot[1/x^5, {x, PR1[[1, 1]], PR1[[1, 2]] - extX/5}, PlotRange -> PR1],

   Graphics[{Thickness[lw], Arrow[{{PR1[[1, 1]], AO[[2]]}, {PR1[[1, 2]], AO[[2]]}}]}],
   Graphics[{Thickness[lw], Arrow[{{AO[[1]], PR1[[2, 1]]}, {AO[[1]], PR1[[2, 2]]}}]}],

   AxesOrigin -> AO,
   PlotRange -> PR,
   PlotRangeClipping -> False,
   ImagePadding -> {{All, 30}, {All, 20}},
   AxesStyle -> Black
]
```

This is the result:

[image]

---

Comment:

This method helped me make a nice ListPlot of data like this,

```
lpData1 = {{937.65, 0.00640611}, {3758.83, 0.00668279}, {2966.86, 0.00709205}, {4184.60, 0.00788002}, {7708.82, 0.00729601}, {2582.33, 0.00830046}, {4728.61, 0.00704802}, {2257.23, 0.00701525}, {2886.35, 0.00801342}, {6477.75, 0.00755450}};
```

`ListPlot[lpData1, PlotRange -> {{0, Max[lpData1] + 500}, {0, 0.0093}}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}], ImagePadding -> None]`  leads to lost axes ticks and numbers near them ([corresponding plot](https://www.docdroid.net/pSj9NJP)); changes of `ImagePadding` and argument of `Arrowheads` don't help.