# Why do Arrowheads interfere with ImagePadding?

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0**

---

In a recent [posting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11605/how-could-i-add-arrows-to-the-axis-of-a-figure/11606#11606), Belisarius solved a problem related to the display of arrows on the x and y axes by setting `ImagePadding->None`.

My question is: why do the parameters of `Arrowheads` interfere with the default settings of `ImagePadding`?  Or is something else going on?

The following illustrates what I am referring to:

```
Grid[{Table[Plot[1/x^5, {x, -20, 20}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, k}]], 
{k, {.0003, .0015, .003, .015, .03}}]}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: images]

Below are the same plots, with `ImagePadding` set to `None`.

```
Grid[{Table[Plot[1/x^5, {x, -20, 20}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, k}], 
ImagePadding -> None], {k, {.0003, .0015, .003, .015, .03}}]}, 
Frame -> All]
```

[image: more plots]

The arrowheads are plotted but too small to be seen at the present scale.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is most likely a bug in the image size calculation routine.

Notwithstanding the arrowheads' sizes are going to be considered as absolute values in image "pixels" for drawing them, when the image size is being calculated the routine reserves enough space to draw the arrows as if they were specified in plot coordinates.

Look in the following example how a `0.05` y axis space is calculated because that is the size of the arrow heads.

```
Framed@Plot[1/x^5, {x, -9, 9}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.05], 
  Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> All, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {Automatic, .01}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Seems convincing. Also, I notice that by constraining the maximum y value (through PlotRange) to .01, you heighten the effect. And by changing it to a max of .1, the effect disappears.

Comment: and +1 for not confusing me with zero-length arrowheads... :)