# Possible bug while plotting homographic function with stylled axes (?!)

Tags: plotting, options

Seems like a bug to me, don't have time to dig more now. WinXP V9.0.1.0

```
With[{
      opt = Sequence[AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotStyle -> {Thick}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
                     ImageSize -> {300, 300}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.05]]
     },
     Row[{Framed@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 4, 6}, opt], 
          Framed@Plot[(-5 + x)/(6 + x)^2, {x, 4, 6}, opt]}]
    ]
```

[image]

and without `AxesStyle`:
[image]

So as we can see, `Arrowheads` is making the trouble but not with every function.

Can you confirm this behaviour on other enviroments?

p.s. **the solution** is `ImagePadding -> spec` ofc, but there should not be the issue.

Comment: This problem seems familiar.  I shall see if I can find another question about it.

Comment: That was easy.  Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11608/121

Comment: @Mr.Wizard indeed. I should have found that :) Thanks.

Comment: Shall I close this question then?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think so.