# Overlaying custom plotmarkers onto graphics primitives using Show

Tags: plotting, graphics, packages

I have found the [custom plotmarkers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84857/how-can-we-make-publication-quality-plotmarkers-without-version-10/85094) package developed by @Alexey Popkov extremely handy for makeing nice, accurate plots. However, I have run into a small issue that I am struggling to make sense of. If I create a graphic object and combine with basic point data in a `ListPlot`e.g.,

```
Show[
 Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 100}]}], 
 ListPlot[{{22, 57}, {88, 91}}, Axes -> False]]
```

I get the following

[image: grey sq and dots]

which I expect.

However, if I try use the `PloygonPlotMarkers` package e.g.,

```
Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]
(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84857/how-can-we-\
make-publication-quality-plotmarkers-without-version-10 *)

fm[name_, size_: 7] := 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[], PolygonMarker[name, Offset[size]]}, 
   AlignmentPoint -> {0, 0}];
(* making markers for plotting -filled*)

Show[Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 100}]}],
 ListPlot[{{22, 57}, {88, 91}},
  PlotMarkers -> fm["Cross", 6],
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  Axes -> False]]
```

the result is unexpected:

[image]

There is only a single point rendered and no `Rectangle`. Adding a `PlotRange ->...` specification within `ListPlot` produces the same unsatisfactory result, however, if I add a `PlotRange -> ...` to `Show` everything plots fine:

[image]

This may not seem like a huge problem here but what I am posting is very much a MWE and this issue gets in the way in more involved plotting overlays.

I suspect there is some issue with padding around the custom plotmarkers, however, I can't see where it is coming from. I also suspect that in the second example all three items are plotted (two crosses and the rectangle) but very small.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and suggest a solution that resolves things a bit more satisfactorily than adding `PlotRange` to `Show`?

Comment: You can add `ImageSize -> {Automatic, 3 size}` to the `Graphics` expression in the definition of `fm`, which fixes the issue. Unfortunately, I'm not sure why exactly this works

Comment: @LukasLang, yep this fixes the problem! Considering all that we want to do is render a small glyph, adding a scaled `ImageSize` declaration is unlikely to cause broader problems in implementation. This should perhaps be written as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, adding an explicit `ImageSize` setting seems to do the trick:

```
fm[name_, size_: 7] := Graphics[
   {
    EdgeForm[],
    PolygonMarker[name, Offset[size]]
    },
   AlignmentPoint -> {0, 0},
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, 3 size}
   ];

Show[
 Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 100}]}],
 ListPlot[{{22, 57}, {88, 91}}, PlotMarkers -> fm["Cross", 6], PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> False]
 ]
```

[image]

I'm not sure why exactly this works, but this solution is fully contained in the definition of `fm`, which should make it more userfriendly

Answer (score 2):

This problem appears to be due to the image padding:

```
Show[
 Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 100}]}],
 ListPlot[
  {{22, 57}, {88, 91}},
  PlotMarkers -> fm["Cross", 6],
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  Axes -> False
  ],
 ImagePadding -> None
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It might be related to [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11608/731).

The reason why adding `PlotRange` works may be because it helps the heuristic that calculates the image padding to choose a better value, but the underlying problem is not that the plot range is wrong to begin with. Let's call your problematic graphics `gr`, then

```
PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[gr]
```

> {{0., 100.}, {0., 100.}}

Comment: Yes, it sounds like this is related. Thanks for the insight.