# Why I cannot change the AxesStyle of the Plot?

Tags: plotting, bugs, options, customization, style

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persists through 11.0.1 or later**

---

I am trying to plot the following single variable function:

$$\small\frac{180 \sqrt{\pi ^2-625 t} \left(\pi ^2 (36 t-25)-1500 t \left(45 t-\sqrt{900 t-\pi ^2}-15\right)\right)}{\pi ^4 \sqrt{2500 t-\pi ^2}}+\tan
   \left(2 \sqrt{\pi ^2-625 t}\right)$$

with code:

```
Plot[(180 Sqrt[π^2-625 t] (π^2 (-25+36 t)-1500 t (-15+45 t-Sqrt[-π^2+900 t])))/(π^4 Sqrt[-π^2+2500 t])+Tan[2 Sqrt[π^2-625 t]],
{t,0.01,0.016},ImageSize->800,
(*AxesStyle->{{Directive[Red, 12],Arrowheads[.035],Thick},{Directive[Red, 12],Arrowheads[.035],Thick}},*)
PlotStyle->Blue]
```

However, I have to comment the `AxesStyle` line above in order to obtain normal image size:

[image]

or it will look like shrinking version below:

[image]

What is the reason? How can I customize the axes style for my case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `ImagePadding` option to None. (With None the exported image is cut a bit on the y-axis so use 10 instead of None)

```
 Plot[(180 Sqrt[π^2 - 625 t] (π^2 (-25 + 36 t) - 
   1500 t (-15 + 45 t -Sqrt[-π^2 + 900 t])))/(π^4 Sqrt[-π^2 + 
   2500 t]) + Tan[2 Sqrt[π^2 - 625 t]], {t, 0.01, 0.016}, 
   AxesStyle -> {{Directive[Red, 12], Arrowheads[.035], 
   Thick}, {Directive[Red, 12], Arrowheads[.035], Thick}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image]

Comment: So it is a bug in handling of the default `ImagePadding -> All` in combination with `AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads[Large], Arrowheads[Large]}`?

Comment: In the case of `ListPlot` we have similar but much lesser severe bug: `ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads[Large], Arrowheads[Large]}]`.

Comment: This issue was noticed before see the comments section in
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11605/how-could-i-add-arrows-to-the-axis-of-a-figure