# How to label into x-axis and y-axis like this picture?

Tags: plotting

I used Geogebra to draw the graph 
[image]

and I tried Mathematica

```
Plot[{(x^2 - 1) (x^2 - 4)}, {x, -2.3, 2.3}, 
    AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.02}], ImagePadding -> None]
```

How can I label and add arrow into x-axis and y-axis like above picture?

[image]

Comment: Use `AxesLabel` to add axis labels.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you very much.

Comment: For the arrows, see: [How could I add arrows to the axis of a figure?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11605/27951).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Plot[
 {(x^2 - 1) (x^2 - 4)}, {x, -2.26, 2.26},
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[Medium],
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 ImagePadding -> 20,
 Ticks -> {Range[-2, 2],
   Append[Range[-2, 4], {-9/4, "-9/4"}]},
 LabelStyle -> {14, Bold},
 AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio,
 Epilog -> Text[Style["0", 14, Bold],
   {0, 0}, {-2, 1.5}]]
```

[image]