# ImagePadding interferes with AxesStyle and AxesLabel

Tags: graphics, padding

I was trying to draw some plots where I wanted to add `Arrowheads` to axes. However, these would completely wreck the plot, putting it completely off the scale. This issue was already discussed in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11605/34848) question, and @Dr. belisarius offered a solution.

Now I'm facing another problem. If I want to set `AxesLabel` property along with `AxesStyle->Arrowheads[{0,0.05}]`, the axes labels are not shown when `ImagePadding->None`. (I'll use examples from the aforementioned question to illustrate)

```
Plot[1/x^5, {x, -20, 20}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}], 
    ImagePadding -> #, AxesLabel -> {"lbl", None}, 
    ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ {None, All} // 
 GraphicsRow[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Am I mistaken or this seams as a bug related to the question before? Does anybody has some solution/workaround?

Comment: This is an annoying bug, but the workaround isn't to set the `ImagePadding` to `None`, but to set it the actual value you want.  Try `ImagePadding -> {{0, 30}, {0, 0}}`, and then adjust the $\{\{left, right\}, \{top, bottom\}\}$ values to your needs.

Comment: @JasonB. Works well... Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use my [graphicsInformation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431) function to determine the required explicit [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding). Apply the function to the plot with default `ImagePadding`:

```
plot = Plot[1/x^5, {x,-20,20}, AxesLabel->{"lbl",None}];
padding = "ImagePadding" /. graphicsInformation[plot]
```

> {{1.71429, 19.}, {1.5, 0.5}}

Then, use this [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding) in your plot:

```
Show[plot, AxesStyle->Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}], ImagePadding -> padding]
```

[image]

Comment: The question to which you posted the original answer incidentally is another issue with which I'm currently struggling (aligning images). Thanks, you saved me a lot of time.